# Tagging iPhone Questions

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Does the "objective-c" tag apply to iPhone questions? Personally, I feel it should be about the language itself, or platform independent questions, not questions where it is like "How do I do this with the iPhone SDK" -- while the SDK does happen to use Objective-C, I don't think that warrants a tag.

Secondly, there seem to be a huge number of tags relating to iPhone development. Can we consolidate them into one "iphone" tag to replace "iphone-sdk"? It'd just be logical to me to have one tag for one kind of question.

Edit: Another question: I've also seen lots of "Xcode" questions, maybe without that tag in particular, but still asking for how to do something in Xcode. Should those also be moved to the "iphone" (or "iphone-sdk"?) tag, and replace "Xcode" with "iPhone"?

Edit: I'm not sorry, at least yet :P.

Answer (score 1):

About your first question:
Most novice programmers use the XCode IDE and The Interface Builder heavily which (opposite of Visual Studio or Netbeans) doesn't show the generated code.

Theoretically, you can build a full application without writing 10 lines in ObjC. So your answer in this area should include how to make it in the IDE not only in the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, objective-c can and does often apply to iPhone questions.  Some iPhone related questions can be answered without an objective-c solution, but many do involve the language.
2. Please propose a list of iPhone tags that should be changed or merged for discussion (probably in a separate question) and see what others think.
3. No, XCode and iPhone are not synonyms.

Comment: I meant that the questions are /not/ about Xcode, but about the iPhone SDK itself: the Xcode IDE is just where they are working, and has nothing to do with the question itself (often they are from new programmers stating "In Xcode, I can type XXX to do this, but XYX doesn't work to do that." or similar).

Comment: @chpwn - If the question has nothing to do with xcode, then sure, the tag needs to be removed.  But that would have to be done on a case by case basis.  If you see such a situation, go ahead and re-tag it.

Answer (score 1):

There are questions about Objective-C which don't involve iPhone development (Mac OSX questions) and questions about iPhone development which don't involve Objective-C (Xcode shortcuts, app store questions). You can differentiate between these questions with the tag. It's the same with Xcode. Not all questions tagged xcode are for iPhone.

There's another case like this, with the cocoa and cocoa-touch tags. The code for cocoa-touch can be quite different (different methods available) so both tags are needed.

I've used tags to make it clear what area I need an answer for. If a Mac developer sees the cocoa-touch tag, they know (for example) that the answer can't use bindings or garbage collection.